# How to order Two Table result MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I get the result from below query and i need to order by id with DESC order. How to add order by function in below query.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM updated_post LEFT JOIN reporter_post ON updated_post.id = reporter_post.id 
UNION 
SELECT * 
  FROM reporter_post RIGHT JOIN updated_post ON reporter_post.id != updated_post.id
```

Comment: `... ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: I mostly use this syntax : `Select * from (Select Query) as FinalQuery Order By FinalQuery.id Desc`

Comment: Radim Basca i received the error like  Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous

Comment: @Sabish.M see the Mureinik response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following:

- Use field names instead of `*` in queries
- Wrap the `UNION` query into another `SELECT` and apply `ORDER BY`

e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT updated_post.id AS id, <other fields> 
      FROM updated_post LEFT JOIN reporter_post ON updated_post.id = 
    reporter_post.id 
    UNION 
    SELECT reporter_post.id AS id, <other fields> 
      FROM reporter_post RIGHT JOIN updated_post ON reporter_post.id != 
    updated_post.id
) a
ORDER BY a.id DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you. Working.

Comment: Is possible to use with * instead of field names.

Comment: @Sabish.M nope, as two tables have different column names for `id` and we want to order by id, we need to assign an `alias`, and in order to do that, we need to use field names and not `*`.

Answer (score 1):

To quote [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

> To use an `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` clause to sort or limit the entire `UNION` result, parenthesize the individual `SELECT` statements and place the `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` after the last one.

EDIT:
There are two columns named `id` in the result (as noted in the comments) - `updated_post.id` and `reporter_post.id`. You should fully qualify one of them (they are, of course, equal according to the `where` clause) in order to use it:

So, in your case:

```
(SELECT    * 
 FROM      updated_post 
 LEFT JOIN reporter_post ON updated_post.id = reporter_post.id)
UNION
(SELECT *
 FROM   reporter_post 
 RIGHT JOIN updated_post ON reporter_post.id != updated_post.id)
ORDER BY reporter_post.id DESC
```

Comment: Error "Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous"

Comment: @Sabish.M exactly, you need to use column names instead of `*`, have a look at my answer.

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1250 - Table 'reporter_post' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause